# What is a way to simplify linking multiple libraries in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'm new to CMake and trying to learn to use it for a simple project. If I have a CMakeLists.txt file that looks like this:

```
add_executable(alpha alpha.cpp)
add_executable(beta beta.cpp)

add_library(one STATIC one.cpp)
add_library(two STATIC two.cpp)

target_link_libraries(alpha one)
target_link_libraries(alpha two)
target_link_libraries(beta one)
target_link_libraries(beta two)
```

Is there a way to simplify this sort of pattern? What I would like is to define something like `all_libraries` that contains both `one` and `two`, and then only have to do one linking per binary. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use interface libraries:

```
add_library(all_libraries INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(all_libraries
    INTERFACE
        one
        two
)
... then later ...
target_link_libaries(alpha PUBLIC all_libraries)
```

You can use variable:

```
set(all_libraries one two)
.. then later ..
target_link_libraries(alpha PUBLIC ${all_libraries})
```

Notes:

- I would advise to always explicit specify the the PUBLIC, PRIVATE and INTERFACE keywords.
- I would go with interface libraries. It's nice to have a big project, expose different mix of libraries as a single interface library, than you only link another big project against that interface. Gives nice control and look of it.